# VeriFIX test automation in Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, fix-protocol

We are working with a client that uses [VeriFIX](http://www.itiviti.com/products-services/products/verifix-by-itiviti/) to test their FIX message flow.  Whilst they have built up lots of tests in many suites, it is a manual process to run them and to collate the results.

On the [VeriFIX](http://www.itiviti.com/products-services/products/verifix-by-itiviti/) website it says

> *Incorporate tests into nightly builds using VeriFIX’s command-line script player.*

but I cannot find any details on how to to it.  Does anyone have any experience in running VeriFIX tests in a continuous integration server (ideally a Jenkins pipeline).

Many thanks.

Comment: Here's their contact details: http://www.itiviti.com/contact/ so I would call them and ask about the auto testing scripts

Comment: @Nik: Did you run using Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run VeriFIX playlists in batch mode from the command line:

"%VERIFIX_HOME%\verifixbatch\verifixbatch.exe" -version "FIX (x.y)" -playlist "myplaylist" -disablelogging "false"

Answer (score 0):

If you have received the user manual with your installation of veriFIX, the details of how to integrate with CI are in there.

To integrate veriFIX with Jenkins you will create batch files containing tests and run the batch files as jobs in Jenkins.
The placement of your veriFIX installation is important. If your veriFIX is on a users machine, as is often the case, separate from the environment machine Jenkins resides on, there can be difficulties getting the tests to run.
If you have a centralised install of veriFIX things are much easier.